# Using Xna Framework classes in Windows Phone Runtime apps

Tags: c#, audio, xna, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime) app and I want to be able to play multiple sounds simultaneously. To my knowledge the only way of doing that on Windows Phone is by using the [SoundEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx) class located in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio. The problem is I can't seem to correctly reference this class; I can see the namespace in my app's object browser but when I try to add a 'using' statement it doesn't seem to find it. When I manually add a reference to the dll file my project won't compile and throws this error when compiling:

> Cannot find type System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException in module mscorlib.dll.

Is it even possible to use Xna classes in Runtime apps (all the online examples seem to implement SoundEffect on Silverlight apps)? And if not then is there any alternative available using which I can play multiple sounds?

Answer (score 0):

The `SoundEffect` class has been removed from version window phone 8.1. So you can not add the effects with audio.